# Windows Server 2019 - Running GUI Application through OpenSSH protocol

Tags: user-interface, ssh

I need to run remotely GUI Desktop App when connected through SSH.
Is this even achievable? When I try to run app(any GUI) it just hangs there and does nothing.
I need to explicitly make this work with SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering how to run GUI applications using psexec, this is the solution:
psexec64 is located in C:\Windows

```
psexec64 -accepteula -nobanner \\SERVER.company.co -u DOMAIN\user -p password -h -i 2 C:\\Windows\notepad.exe
```

Note: You can run any exe on the server, as well as you can run locally,
also if you need to run it from linux here is solution:

First install winexe: https://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/ - google for installing from cli

```
winexe -U DOMAIN/user%password //SERVER.company.co "psexec64 -u DOMAIN\user-p password -accepteula -nobanner -h -i 2 C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
```

Hopefully this will help someone